# Hyperledger Fabric Go Chaincode - Signing inside chaincode code

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, sign, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm working on Hyperledger Fabric with Golang Chaincode and I have the following question.

Is it possible to have each endorser sign something in the code of the chaincode?

For example: I have a client proposing a transaction and I want to not only have the transaction approved (and signed by the endorsers so the client sends it to the ordering service) but also a string inside the code signed so the client can receive this string signed and use it for other purposes. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to go back to the roots to learn about the terms in context of fabric. Try to understand the basics first to transmit then what you actually want to achieve by asking here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer kajuken. I suppose when someone asks here in Stack Overflow something such as "What is the difference between an int and a float" you will answer the same thing? Since they can go back to the "roots" and learn.

Comment: Tried to give an answer. Didnt fully understand your problem though. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I should have explained better probably. What I want to do is try to make each endorser sign for example a string, and the client receives as the transaction response a list/array of strings containing the same string signed by each endorser. Or for example make an endorser create a signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand you want to get the identification of the user invoking the chaincode.

If this is the case then you can use cid GetMSPID https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid#GetMSPID or getID https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid#GetID

So you can take the identity of the user as a string an you can use it as signature as you like

Anyhow, i believe the first step is to catch the user identity i.e the user name and then user it as you wish. For me cid getMSPID did the trick in similar situation

Hope this helped